# Entity Framework 6 error: Unable to update the EntitySet 'table1'

Tags: .net, entity-framework

full error is:

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'table1' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation
```

From looking around, it seems this error is caused by a lack of a primary key on `table1`.  I have checked my .edmx file and the table in SQL server and both show that a primary key is specified.  What else should I be looking at?

Comment: how about showing some code? should probably look on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/220262bd-85d4-4f29-96a8-4a7d1d2c8293/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-deletefunction-element?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 1):

If you are using edmx the DefiningQuery will be defined for database views and EF will treat an EntitySet created from view as read-only. If you want to be able to manipulate your data you will need to map stored procedures which will be used for CUD (Create/Update/Delete) operations.